# Serverless handler for Apollo Server throws error that it cant identify events on Netlify

Tags: graphql, serverless, apollo-server, netlify

**Context:**
I am trying to deploy GraphQL using Apollo Server Lambda through Netlify. My handler is as below:

**Code:**

```
exports.handler = server.createHandler({
  cors: {
    origin: '*'
  }
});
```

I was able to build and deploy successfully on Netlify - however the server threw an error at launch. Netlify is looking for an event to trigger but the Apollo Server handler I have used does not provide. How do we connect this handler to a handler that uses events?

**Error Message:**

```
{"errorType":"Error","errorMessage":"Unable to determine event source based on event.","trace":["Error: Unable to determine event source based on event.","    at getEventSourceNameBasedOnEvent (/var/task/node_modules/@vendia/serverless-express/src/event-sources/utils.js:88:9)","    at proxy (/var/task/node_modules/@vendia/serverless-express/src/configure.js:38:51)","    at handler (/var/task/node_modules/@vendia/serverless-express/src/configure.js:99:12)","    at Runtime.handler (/var/task/node_modules/apollo-server-lambda/dist/ApolloServer.js:51:27)"]}
```

Answer (score 6):

It looks like the request doesn't contain some [AWS lambda specific event params](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/set-up-lambda-proxy-integrations.html) when using Netlify CLI while `@vendia/serverless-express` [expects them](https://github.com/vendia/serverless-express/blob/mainline/src/event-sources/utils.js#L88). I was able to fix a similar case in local dev environment with this:

```
const serverHandler = server.createHandler({
  cors: {
    origin: '*'
  }
});

exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
  return serverHandler(
    {
      ...event,
      requestContext: event.requestContext || {},
    },
    context,
    callback
  );
}
```

Comment: Awessome! Is it still working once deployed?